# 13 States: Which is missing?

Tags: pattern, geography

This list of twelve US states is missing only one.  Can you figure out which one and why?

- Alabama
- Alaska
- Arizona
- Arkansas
- Connecticut
- Georgia
- Illinois
- Indiana
- Kentucky
- Ohio
- Oklahoma
- Oregon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it

> North Carolina

Since those 13 states

> Contain the letter they begin with more than once

Comment: Got it in one.  Still searching for that balance between way too easy and way too hard...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman maybe you shouldn't have given us 12, maybe 8 and let us get the other 5

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil: Possibly, though the more states you remove, the greater the chance that the remaining ones will have some _other_ property in common that you didn't intend.  Oh well.  (My first instinct was to list _countries_ with that property, but there's a lot more of them - and it's a dead giveaway that so many of them start with 'A'.  Actually ALL of the A-countries work, just like all the A-states.  Geographic names really like A's for some reason.)

Comment: Its a good puzzle, wasn't as obvious for me since i was overthinking it. i was looking at a map ;-).